# Copying hashtag comments recursively within <blocks>

Tags: replace

I have two files, one with blocks like

```
<record>
line1
line2
line3
#model bla bla bla
</record>
```

while the other file has exactly the same number of  blocks, but without the hashtag comments, ie like

```
<record>
line4
line5
line7
line8
line9
line10
</record>
```

So, what I want to do, is to copy from the 1st  block of the first file the hashtag to the 1st block of the second file so that my other file also looks like

```
<record>
line4
line5
line7
line8
line9
line10
#model bla bla bla
</record>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in the same order small code in `python`

```
import os
os.rename("second","second~")
a=[]
f=open("first","r")
lines=f.readlines()
b=-1
for line in lines:
    if "</record>" in str(line):
        if b!=-1:
            a.append(lines[b])
        else:
            print "</record> found in first line"
    b=b+1
f.close()
b=0
destination = open("second","w")
source = open("second"+"~","r")
for line in source:
    if "</record>" in str(line):
        destination.write(a[b])
        b=b+1
    destination.write(line)
source.close()
destination.close()
```

note:first is the file containing the hashtag and second is the file without hashtag

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this! Indeed it works, but the problem is that in the header of the first file, there are several other hastags that also include the #model - So, what I actually need is from each <record> to copy the line just before the closing block </record> - This would insure that I get the correct line  - Would that be possible ?

Thanks again!

Comment: edited :) hope this helps

Comment: Sweet!!!! 

thanks bunch for your precious help! It works..almost perfect, except the fact that is copies the #hastag from the very first <record> block to all blocks of the target file..It should copy from *each* <record> block to the corresponding block in the target...

Sorry if was not clear...

Comment: dude i corrected it now sorry i by mistake left `b=b+1` there, third line from last

Comment: sorry...not working
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashtag.py", line 20, in <module>
    destination.write(a[b])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: sorry man i placed `b=b+1` in wrong place

Answer (score 1):

From your sample, it looks like this simple awk command should be enough:

```
awk '/<\/record/{"grep \\^\\# file1"|getline a; print a};1' file2
```

Or, if as figured out from the further requirements exposed in the comments to the other answer which you forgot to add to your question ;-), hash tags may appear outside `<record>` blocks:

```
sed '/<record>/,/<\/record>/!d;/^#/!d' < file1 |
  awk '/<\/record/{getline a < "-"; print a};1' file2
```